# Looping through SQL Server results on my .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, webforms

I'm new to ASP.NET and C#. I'm conversant in SQL Server and am having a heck of a time moving over from the traditional ASP world.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Chapters 
(
     ChapterID NUMERIC, 
     ChapterName NVARCHAR, 
     ChapterDesc NVARCHAR
)

SELECT mChapterID, ChapterName, ChapterDesc 
FROM Chapters

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CHAPTER NAME</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chaptid" value="<%=Chapters.ChapterID %>"></td>
        <td><%=Chapters.ChapterName %></td>
        <td><%=Chapters.ChapterDesc %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr> // 10 rows
</table>
```

There are 10 rows returned from the query. How do I loop through them in my table rows so I can display all 10?

EDIT: I added a checkbox as the first field

Comment: You should look into a GridView Control. It will generate a html table.

Comment: It web forms, you don't write loops. You use databinding, either to an ASP:Repeater or a ASP:GridView or similar.

Comment: If you don't have a valid reason to work with asp.net I really suggest you to not loose time here and go straight to Asp.net MVC  and Core libraries. You will get our beloved loops and a far more efficient framework

Comment: There is one DB related rule that holds true in most programming scenarios, but doubly so in web programming: Retreive as little as possible, but as much as you can in one query. One the one hand, do not retrieve too much. If you need any filtering or paging, always do that in the query. Especially in Web devleoplement, you got nowhere near the internal memory to do filtering on the programm side. Or overload the user with way to much data. On the other hand, do not do 10 small queries if a single one could do it too. Queries have overhead. 10 rows of 3 Columns is a pretty good sweet spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by chance you want to create the XML/HTML in SQL Server in one shot...

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ChapterID] int,[ChapterName] varchar(50),[ChapterDesc] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Chapter 1','This is the 1st chapter')
,(2,'Chapter 2','This is the 2nd chapter')

Select (Select th='ID'
              ,null
              ,th='Chapter Name'
              ,null
              ,th='Description'
              ,null 
          For XML Path('tr'),type)
      ,(Select td= ( Select [@type]='checkbox'
                           ,[@name]='chaptid'
                           ,[@value]=[ChapterID]
                      For XML Path('input'),type)
              ,null
              ,td=[ChapterName]
              ,null
              ,td=[ChapterDesc] 
          From @YourTable 
           For XML Path('tr'),Type) 
 For XML Path(''),Root('table')
```

**Returns**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Chapter Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chaptid" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>Chapter 1</td>
    <td>This is the 1st chapter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chaptid" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>Chapter 2</td>
    <td>This is the 2nd chapter</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: These seems pretty straightforward and possibly usable. I changed the original question to reflect that I don't really need the CategoryID in the first results field but instead a checkbox. Could you maybe point me in a direction?

Comment: Outstanding. This is going to work I believe. It also pointed me in a direction to learn an entirely knew coding methodology. Thanks Much!!!

Comment: @Gregbert Happy to help;   The learning part is the fun part  :)

Comment: @Gregbert SQL Server supports the generation and consumption of XML  You can think of HTML as XML  You can search "sql server xml tutorial"

Answer (score 1):

John Cappelletti pointed me in a direction and here's what I eventually came up with. THANKS JOHN!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Chapters 
(
     ChapterID NUMERIC, 
     ChapterName NVARCHAR, 
     ChapterDesc NVARCHAR
)

DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @body = N'<table>'
    + N'<tr><th>Check</th><th>Chapter Name</th><th>Chapter Desc</th></tr>'
    + CAST((
        SELECT  '<input type="checkbox" name="ChapterID" value="'+CONVERT(varchar(10),[c].[mChapterID])+'">' AS td,
                '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'+[c].[ChapterName]+'</span>' AS td, 
                [c].[ChapterDesc] AS td
        FROM    [ModuleChapters] c
        WHERE   [c].[inActive] = 0
          AND   [c].[isDeleted] = 0
        FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    + N'</table>'

SELECT tBody = @body
```